# Form Validation in Bootstrap Tabs (AngularJS)

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, validation, tabs

**Some context:**

- AngularJS 1.4
- Bootstrap 3.3.7

I'm using **Bootstrap** *tabs navigation and panels* inside a **form**. 
Inside each panel I have **an input** that is **required**.

The *default validation* is not able to **focus** (*change the active tab*) and show the *error message* **after** the **validation**.

(console.log):

```
An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable.
```

A lot of "solutions" mention to remove the required attribute (from the hidden inputs) but that is not what I want because I need to have all inputs validated.

I tried to use ngModel validators but I'm not sure if it's a valid path for what I need.

What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to **check the input's value** and *if invalid show it's tab*, **upon form submit**.

Thank you.

[**Solution found!**]

> Controller:

```
$scope.tabsValidation = form => {
        let first = jQuery(`form[name="${form.$name}"] input.ng-invalid`).closest('.tab-pane');
        let firstID = first.attr('id');
        jQuery('.nav a[data-target="#' + firstID + '"]').tab('show');
    };
```

> View (form):

```
<button class="btn" type="submit" ng-click="tabsValidation(formName)">
    Submit
</button>
```

From what I understand, the *ng-click* its executed before the actual form submit/validation.

Comment: Solution found and added to the description... you may close this. Thank you